# Sorting Map in complexity of O(log(n))

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, complexity-theory

How can I sort the map (with complexity of `O(log(n))`) by id of the player or the name of the player??

```
private static final Map<Integer,Player> PLAYERS= new TreeMap<>();
       static {
           PLAYERS.put(1, new Player(1, "messi"));
           PLAYERS.put(2, new Player(7, "ronaldo"));
           PLAYERS.put(3, new Player(3, "neymar"));
           PLAYERS.put(4, new Player(4, "iniesta"));
           PLAYERS.put(5, new Player(5, "ronaldo"));
           PLAYERS.put(6, new Player(2, "pique"));
           PLAYERS.put(7, new Player(6, "suarez"));
       }
```

i did this comperator for example:

```
public static Comparator<Player> PlayerNameComparator = new 
Comparator<Player>() {

public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {

String playerName1 = p1.getName().toUpperCase();
String playerName2 = p2.getName().toUpperCase();

return playerName1.compareTo(playerName2);
}
};
```

but I don't know how to fix this:

```
public static Collection getAllByName() {

Map sortedPlayersByName = new TreeMap(PLAYERS);

Collections.sort(sortedPlayersByName, Player.PlayerNameComparator);
return sortedPlayersByName.values();    
 }
```

Comment: Read [this](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/how-to-sort-a-treemap-by-value-in-java/)

Comment: You can't sort a map, period.

Comment: so how can I sort the collection by names and still be with complexity of O(log(n))?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Tree map in your example. It will by default sort by key unless you write a comparator to sort it by values. Since Tree map uses red black tree, your insertion time will be O(logN).